# Using sorted() on a dict

Tags: python, list

i'm trying to sort a dict with tasks as a key, and trying to untie them if there is more than one translator in the dict:

So for example, after I iterate the keys and values, since key['harry potter volume 24'] has 2 possible translators, I want to untie them using some of the other paramenters (for example, the 1* but had no luck using lambda dicts iterators since i allways get the error that it's out of range. Same thing when i transformed the dict to a list.

Any ideias? Thanks

Edit1: Deleted for replacement.

Edit2:

```
newList = []
for k,v in dic.iteritems():
    if len(v) > 1:
        newList.append(v)



#now i'm trying to use sorted to untie it on a parameter 
#(for example the speed which is the 4 position  on a list of lists so then i can return the 
#[0] position translator)

n = sorted(newList, key=lambda t:t[4])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Família\Desktop\functions_dict.py", line 70, in <module>
    n = sorted(newList, key=lambda t:t[4])
  File "C:\Users\Família\Desktop\functions_dict.py", line 70, in <lambda>
    n = sorted(newList, key=lambda t:t[4])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do. Can you post an example of the output you'd want?

Comment: Also in general it is a very bad idea to shadow a built-in function. Don't assign things to `dict`.

Comment: Also there's no way to tell what's wrong with your code if you don't post the code.

Comment: @ssdecontrol thanks for the reply, i tried to explain what i want in the first edit, the dict is mearly a word, i'm not using it to describe it in python. I'll try to find the best part of the code i've came up with

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ssdecontrol hope it's a bit less confusing now

Comment: I think it's still unclear what you mean by "untie". Could you post the return value that you are expecting?

Comment: @antonagestam sorry, should appear the expected result now, making me able to return the translator on position [0] which would be the best choice for the task

Comment: so, you want to order the values of each key in the dictionary?? or extract the values list of each key which is a list with multiples element and order each one?

Comment: @Copperfield I'd like to order the values for each key if possible in a dict, but i wasn't able to do it, so i turned the ones that fit the condition of having more then 1 translator, and now i'm trying to order the resulting list of lists by a value that is inside a tuple

Comment: Please, if you are showing complicated data you want treated by your code, put it in a human reable form. I fixed some of the formatting on your input data so that I could figure  out what it was - but there is room for improvement

Comment: For what it's worth, in Python `dict` order is undefined and cannot be changed by the user. You have to use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple, use the [list.sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort), to well ,sort the elements inside the dict itself and inside those list in place without making any copy of the data (unless that that is what you want)

```
>>> test={'com os holandeses': [], 'harry potter volume 24': [('Ana Tavares', ['(english)', '(portuguese)', '1*', '0.501', '2000', '20000', '2304', '08:11:2016']), ('Rita Carvalho', ['(english)', '(portuguese)', '1*', '0.633', '5000', '400000', '18023', '09:11:2016'])], 'emailToJane': [('Paula Guerreiro', ['(french)', '(portuguese)', '2*', '0.900', '3500', '45000', '21689', '11:11:2016'])], 'osudy dobrÃ©ho vojÃ¡ka Å\xa0vejka za svÄ\x9btovÃ© vÃ¡lky': [('MikolÃ¡s Janota', ['(czech)', '(english; portuguese)', '3*', '1.780', '2000', '200000', '4235', '08:11:2016'])]}
>>> 
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(test['harry potter volume 24'])
[('Ana Tavares',
  ['(english)',
   '(portuguese)',
   '1*',
   '0.501',
   '2000',
   '20000',
   '2304',
   '08:11:2016']),
 ('Rita Carvalho',
  ['(english)',
   '(portuguese)',
   '1*',
   '0.633',
   '5000',
   '400000',
   '18023',
   '09:11:2016'])]
>>> for v in test.values():
        v.sort(key=lambda t: float(t[1][3]), reverse=True)


>>> pprint(test['harry potter volume 24'])
[('Rita Carvalho',
  ['(english)',
   '(portuguese)',
   '1*',
   '0.633',
   '5000',
   '400000',
   '18023',
   '09:11:2016']),
 ('Ana Tavares',
  ['(english)',
   '(portuguese)',
   '1*',
   '0.501',
   '2000',
   '20000',
   '2304',
   '08:11:2016'])]
>>>
```

the meat of the deal is here

```
for v in test.values():
    v.sort(key=lambda t: float(t[1][3]), reverse=True)
```

`t` is each element inside each list, which in your case it can be expressed as `(Name,ListData)` then `t[1]` is said ListData and from there we want what you call "speed" (whatever that means here), I transform that to a float so it be orderer by it numeric value, and the rest should be self explanatory

Comment: This worked kinda like i wanted it! But i have a new problem that i'm not sure if i should post here or in a new thread

Comment: glad you liked it. If this new problem is not about sorting this dictionary or sorting stuff, I think a new thread is the right choice

Comment: ups already updated, but ill erase that part and make a new one, hope you can help there too! thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

One can pass a `key` parameter to the `sorted` function - this is a function that will take in the item to be sorted, and return another Python object that will compare naturally with the built-in operators.

Therefore, you can have whatever complexity you want in a function to be used as "key", and still do all your sorting in a single call. The Key function takes a single Python object - in th case of a dictionary you will want a tuple of key, value such as provided by the `items` method.

But on a second reading, you want to sort the values, regardless of the keys - that, yes, will require one call to sorted to each dictionary item:

```
def mykey(translator):
    if not translator: 
         return ''  # returns empty lists and avoids index error
    key = translator[1][2]  # Should be string '*1' in your example;
    # concatenate the return value with more
    # fields if needed.
    return key

new_dict = {}
for key, value in dicionary.items()  
    #  Don't use iteritems - it is Python3 incompatible, and buys you almost nothing but for HUGE datasets
    # Also avoid one letter variables if they don't improve readability
    new_dict[key] = sorted(value, key=mykey)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the `newList` you demonstrate is actually a *list of lists*.

Here it is "pretty-printed":

```
[
    [
        [
            "Ana Tavares",
            [
                "(english)",
                "(portuguese)",
                "1*",
                "0.701",
                "2000",
                "20000",
                "2304",
                "08:11:2016"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "Rita Carvalho",
            [
                "(english)",
                "(portuguese)",
                "1*",
                "0.633",
                "5000",
                "400000",
                "18023",
                "09:11:2016"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

`newList` is actually a list containing exactly one element, another list. That is, the data structure is something like this:

```
- list:
  - list:
    - list:
      - string
      - list, containing:
       - string
       - string
       - string
       - string
       - string
       - string
       - string
       - string
    - list:
      - string
      - list, containing:
       - string
       - string
       - string
       - string
       - string
       - string
       - string
       - string
```

I suspect this is not the data structure you intended to produce. But the reason you're getting the error is that you are calling `sorted` on the outermost list, which only has one element. That element, in turn, only has two elements. So `lambda t: t[4]` fails because it's being called on a length-two list.